# Arp-scan or netdiscover cannot see VMWare machine

Tags: kali-linux, vmware, arp

I am running Kali Linux in a dual boot laptop. I have VMWare player installed and I am running some machines to practice pentesting.

I am given the IP adress for the VMWare machine. So then I was told to set the network adapter of the VM to NAT.

Then when I run `arp-scan` or `netdiscover`, I am not able to get the IP of the VM. I only get the IPs of the laptop and others, the laptop's IP is 192.168.100.54 and the IP of the VM is a different one (192.168.244.133).

I can ping it though and I'm able to run an Nmap scan with now problems. I tried bridged and host-only and no VM show up on my ARP scans. I just want to understand why it doesn't show up.

Comment: The intention (rather than the method used) of your question is difficult to understand. Are you trying to check if there's an ARP leak detectable? Then you could detect the laptop's own IP address in the VM's LAN still from the Ethernet LAN where 192.168.100.0/24 are used, but not the VM's IP address itself. Try searching for 192.168.244.1 instead of 192.168.244.133 (assuming the VM's gateway is this value).